# Is @RequestBody should be wrapped with Mono Publisher in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm study Spring-Webflux and I just wonder should I wrap my @RequestBody object with Mono Publisher as well?

For instance: 
`@RequestBody Mono<SavePriceViewModel> saveModel`

Example:

```
@PostMapping("/item")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<PriceViewModel>> createHeaderAndItem(@RequestBody Mono<SavePriceViewModel> saveModel) {
   return service.createHeaderAndItem(saveModel).doOnSuccess(r -> log.debug("createHeaderAndItem() returned."));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request body need not be mono and we can return a `Mono<ResponseModel>` not required ResponseEntity

```
@PostMapping("/item")
public Mono<PriceViewModel> createHeaderAndItem(@RequestBody SavePriceViewModel saveModel) {
   return service.createHeaderAndItem(saveModel).doOnSuccess(r -> log.debug("createHeaderAndItem() returned."));
}
```

For more info on serializing and deserializing for check this.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs

> When decoding to a multi-value publisher (e.g. Flux), each TokenBuffer
>   is passed to the ObjectMapper as soon as enough bytes are received for
>   a fully formed object. The input content can be a JSON array, or
>   line-delimited JSON if the content-type is `"application/stream+json"`.

Comment: Thanks. But when we consider another case -> Flux. @RequestBody SavePriceViewModels will be a JSON array then mapping JSON object into POJO classes takes some time. Should we use then Flux e.g. ```@RequestBody Flux<SavePriceViewModels> saveModels```

Comment: Yes @SlawomirNowak you can use that for JSON array, Updated ans with a link for more info on this topic.

Comment: Yeah ok, but swagger auto generate it with @RequestBody Mono<...>